Issue with Access Rules for Attachments / odoo 17
In a custom module , I add new field ir_attchment_ids .
When connecting wih other user (not admin) , I got this error .
Uh-oh! Looks like you have stumbled upon some top-secret records.

Sorry, user (id=8) doesn't have 'read' access to:
- Attachment (ir.attachment)

If you really, really need access, perhaps you can win over your friendly administrator with a batch of freshly baked cookies.

Here is my code
Python :
class AddAttachment(models.Model):
    _name = "add.attachment"
    
     attachment_ids = fields.Many2many("ir.attachment", string="My Attachment") 

XML :
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <record id="add_attachment_form_views" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">add.ttachment.form</field>
        <field name="model">add.ttachment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Account">
                <sheet>
                    <group>
                         <field name="attachment_ids" />
                    </group>
                </sheet>
            </form>
        </field>
    </record>
    <record id="add_attachment_tree_views" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">add.ttachment.tree</field>
        <field name="model">add.ttachment</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <tree string="Account">
              <field name="attachment_ids" />
            </tree>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="open_add_attachment" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Add Attachment</field>
        <field name="res_model">add.attachment</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>
    </record>

SECURITY
id,name,model_id:id,group_id:id,perm_read,perm_write,perm_create,perm_unlink
access_add_attachment,add.attachment,model_add_attachment,,1,1,1,1

Any idea please ?
Thanks.

I think the problem is you really don't have the access to the model ir.attachment. Maybe try to add this to your ir.model.access.csv:
access_ir_attachment,access_ir_attachment,base.model_ir_attachment,base.group_user,1,1,1,1

